# Why am I getting a match with "incomplete" when looking only for "complete"?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to find out what is wrong with my formula I have created (see below) everything is working fine, but when I check for the word "complete" it's brining up "incomplete" which I don't need it to do that.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"correction","change","legal","property","terms","vesting","payment","date","interest","correction","amended","chg","address","exhibit","add","notary","complete","amnt"},V2)))>0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search will return parts of words.

To search for complete words change it to:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({" correction "," change "," legal "," property "," terms "," vesting "," payment "," date "," interest "," correction "," amended "," chg "," address "," exhibit "," add "," notary "," complete "," amnt "}," " & V2 & " ")))>0
```

By adding spaces before and after it will only pick up the full word and not any extras.

Comment: What happens if `"complete"` is the first (or perhaps only) word in the cell that you are searching?

Comment: I added spaces to the beginning and end of V2 `" " & V2 & " "`  So it will not matter. @JohnColeman

Comment: I see -- clever. Though punctuation could still be an issue. A more robust solution might require VBA and regular expressions, though that might be overkill.

Comment: Additionally, if **complete** or **incomplete** was the entire value of the cell, you wouldn't be using the [SEARCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SEARCH-function-F79EF0B8-0991-4FC1-93B0-627F019A69E3); just direct compare.

Comment: @JohnColeman to deal with punctuation we could use nested substitutes to change them to spaces.  But that would become cumbersome and as you said vba may be better suited.